# How to make dcases environment work in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, cases, macports

I'm using Kile (kde4) on Mac OS. I can use the `cases` environment just fine but my version of Kile doesn't have `dcases`. I'm using Kile via MacPorts. Does anyone know of a way to update my distribution so I can access this environment? I'm not too good with MacPorts so I haven't really touched it after following the directions to get it installed.

Or is there a quick/lazy fix I could do, like maybe defining my own command to do the same things as `dcases`?

Comment: Are you loading the `mathtools` package?

Comment: Do you want autocomplete in Kile editor for `dcases` environment or if it's with package `\usepackage{mathtools}`

Comment: Thanks guys, that was the issue. Totally forgot that I need mathtools...don't remember doing that the last time :x

Comment: @user1799323 Some useful info: mathtools is package included in a TeX distribution (eg: TeXLive,MiKTeX and MacTeX), which has nothing to do with any LaTeX editor(Kile), Hence title has been modified to reflect the issue.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. answer added.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `dcases` environment is implemented by the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, so you need to load it in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
```